# Using a proxy for traffic coming through Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy

I'm trying to use Charles to inspect web requests from any devices I've connect to my laptop's wifi hotspot. However, none of the outgoing web traffic is captured (unless I originate the request from my laptop).

I enabled my Virtual WiFi Miniport adapter, and then shared my internet connection with it. I checked Windows proxy settings by going to Control Panel > Internet Options > Connection > LAN Settings, and it looks okay. (Charles set this up to be 127.0.0.1:8888, I also tried using the IP address of my laptop.) My phone connects to the adapter just fine.

How can I inspect web traffic coming through my wifi adapter?